# Why did electricity go off when Brian Finch searched for "Eddie Morra NZT"?

Tags: plot-explanation, limitless-tv

2 or 3 times through out the *Limitless* TV series, Brian Finch tried to search for "Eddie Morra NZT" then electricity goes off as soon as he hits Enter. It felt for him (and the audience) that "you're searching for forbidden god-like information".

I know that season 2 is most likely never going to come out. But, is there any logical answer for this?

Comment: I have to rewatch the scenes for a better context, but I think it is meant to invoke that either Eddie Morra or another party is SUPER powerful, in that Mora's information is heavily protected by cyber security system or team. It plays to the show's conspiracy angle.